# NET Regex: {1} not working

Tags: c#, regex

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch("1234567-8A","[0123456789]+-[0123456789K]{1}"))
    Console.WriteLine("It is not match");
else
    Console.WriteLine("It is match");
```

This outputs "It is match", but shouldn't.

Why is the `{1}` not working?

After the `-` I want explicitly 1 character (0 or 1 or 2 or ... or 9 or K)

Comment: You can use `\d` instead of `[0123456789]`, by the way, and `{1}` doesn’t do anything.

Comment: And you can omit the {1} completely, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches because it is a match. You don't specify that that's the end of the string and your test string does indeed have a single digit at the end. Try this instead:

```
[0123456789]+-[0123456789K]{1}$
```

The `$` denotes the end of the string.

Or even better, use `^` for the start of the string too:

```
^[0123456789]+-[0123456789K]{1}$
```

Comment: "and your test string does indeed have a single digit at the end" ...how come is that?

Comment: @sports It's matching `1234567-8`. Without the anchors, there is no requirement to match the entire input string.

Comment: @sports: You string is **1234567-8**A. There is a single digit after the `-` which is what your regex is matching. It doesn't care about the rest of the string (the `A`) because you haven't told it to care about it.

Answer (score 9):

The pattern is not anchored to the end of the string. Try

```
!Regex.IsMatch("1234567-8A","[0123456789]+-[0123456789K]$")
```

Edit: or

```
!Regex.IsMatch("1234567-8A","^[0123456789]+-[0123456789K]$")
```

to anchor to both the start and end (to match the entire string).

Regarding the `{1}`, the reason it's not necessary is that the character class [0123456789K] already means "match one character from this list". Adding `{1}` doesn't change that to mean "match one character from this list and nothing else after it". You need the `$` anchor for that.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx for information on anchors in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex:

```
var parts = "1234567-8A".Split('-');
bool match = parts.Length == 2 && parts[0].All(c=> char.IsNumber(c))
                               && parts[1].Length == 1 
                               && (char.IsNumber(parts[1][1])
                                        || parts[1][1] == 'K')
```

Comment: Is it faster that way? no automata

Answer (score 0):

As an aside comment, you can write your pattern like this:

```
^[0-9]+-[0-9K]$
```